# Parsing in CSharp - how to understand it

Tags: c#, parsing

It's just few days ago that I jumped into learning C# and I already have one problem with understanding basics.. Maybe it's just the language barrier (I'm not English native speaker). Please, could you explain me how to understand parsing? For example: while creating a very simple calculator I wanted to read the first input number (which is a variable `a`). I use this code:

```cs
float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

and the same with `b` for the other number:

```cs
float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I learnt that the `float` is a data type for decimals numbers so what exactly does this particular `Parse()` stands for?

Obviously, I tried to run the application without parsing and it wouldn't work because it reads it as string, but why?  Thank you..

Comment: `a` is a `float`, `ReadLine()` produces a `string`. A conversion is required.

Comment: "I learnt that float is data type for decimals numbers" - no, floating-point numbers are totally different. Try this: `float a = 0.1, b = 0.2, c = 0.3;` and compare if `a + b == c`. The result will surprise you.

Comment: @user3477950 - `float` , `double` and `decimal` are all floating-point types, not 'totally' different, just marginally.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The difference is not marginal at all. Binary vs. decimal floating-point formats behave differently when it comes to representing decimal fractional numbers. Namely, a decimal format **can** do that, whereas a binary format **can't.** This is by no means "marginal".

Comment: @user3477950 - for somebody who asks about `float.Parse()` they are indistinguishable. Your audience matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`, which represents a piece of text. So, from the computer's point of view, what you have after calling `Console.ReadLine()` is a piece of text. It may or may not contain the text "6.0", but from the computer's point of view, it is just a piece of text. As such, you cannot use it to add, subtract etc.

Using the `float.Parse(...)` method, you tell the computer: "This piece of text actually represents a floating point number, could you please read the text and give me back a number, so that I can start doing math with it?".

Answer (score 2):

[Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads text that the user inputs and returns it to the program so that you may do with it what you want. Therefore, the ReadLine method returns a [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to work with a decimal (check the [decimal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead of [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)), you need to convert the string, which is a character sequence, to a number of your desired type, that's where [float.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comes in:

float.Parse accepts a string and if possible, returns a float value.

Almost every type contains the Parse method which is used to transform a string into the calling one.

Comment: "Almost every type contains the Parse method which is used to transform another type of value into the calling one." -"Parsing" always means converting from string, not any other type.

Comment: @Rotem you are tottaly right, I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using, `float.Parse()` is just one of many such methods that take a `String` input value, and attempt to convert it into the target type, here a `float`.

There is a safer alternative, however, and it is `TryParse()`:

```
float a;
if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a))
{
    //do something with your new float 'a'
}
```

In either case, your are asking the framework to inspect the value you provide, and attempt to make a conversion into the requested type.  This topic can be quite deep, so you'll want to consult [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the specifics.